# Cannot create users using devise and Postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I've created an application in which a user can sign up/sign in using a form, and enter an online queue, to do this I've used rails 5 and devise.

Now I'm trying to create new users using Postman as I want to be able to create users via post requests.

I get the following error when I try :

2 errors prohibited this user from being saved:
-Email can't be blank
-Password can't be blank

This is the JSON I try to pass in:

{

```
"users" :{

    "email" : "test@api.com",
    "password" : "123456789"
    "password_confirmation" : "123456789"

}
```

}

I don't know what you would need to see to debug this, but I'll be happy to produce it if you can tell me what you need, thanks!

Comment: `user` singular, show us your `rails s`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you've set up your controller to accept form-data (as is normally done) and you've sent a JSON payload instead. In this case you should try setting your params as form-data in Postman:

```
key                          value
user[email]                  test@api.com
user[password]               123456789
user[password_confirmation]  123456789
```

Also make sure you've whitelisted these fields.

If you're expecting JSON in the request, check and make sure it is parsed correctly.